# Blend in tr::before number with table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have got a HTML table built like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {font-family:'-webkit-system-font', 'HelveticaNeue-Light';}
    </style><style type="text/css">
table.sortable, tbody {
    counter-reset: sortabletablescope;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.sortable, thead tr::before {
    content: "";
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table.sortable, tbody tr::before {
    content: counter(sortabletablescope);
    counter-increment: sortabletablescope;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<center>
<table class="sortable" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Play</th>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=1990">1990</a><br>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
  <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2000">2000</a><br>data3</td><td>data4</td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to move the list number so it looks like its part of the table, and not printed before, so there is no whitespace before "Name" in the table header. Like how it looks here (here the numbers are added manually):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        body {font-family:'-webkit-system-font', 'HelveticaNeue-Light';}
    </style><style type="text/css">
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<center>
<table class="sortable" id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Play</th>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=1990">1. 1990</a><br>data1</td><td>data2</td></tr>
  <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2000">2. 2000</a><br>data3</td><td>data4</td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I have managed to get the number where I want it by using

```
position: relative; bottom: -6px;
position: relative; left: +25px;
```

But that doesn't remove the whitespaces before "Name" in the table header. Is this possible to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a CSS counter indeed  via the `:before` pseudo-element style like a table-cell: *(but there got to be one on each row to preserve the right amount of columns)*

Sizing the pseudo-element will allow you to set a negative text-indent on the first th to align it to the far left

example

```css
/* pseudo tr:before for CSS COUNTER for table tr */

tr:before {
  content: '';
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

thead th:first-child {
  text-indent: -1.5em;
}

tbody {
  counter-reset: trs
}

tbody tr:before {
  counter-increment: trs;
  content: counter(trs)'. ';
  width: 1.5em;
  text-align: right;
}


/* end css counter */

body {
  font-family: '-webkit-system-font', 'HelveticaNeue-Light';
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>

<table class="sortable" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Play</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=1990">1990</a><br>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2000">2000</a><br>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2010">2010</a><br>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2020">2020</a><br>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

*Mind the structure of your table to have no surprise once rendered by browsers.*

---

if it needs to be inside the first cell, then set the counter to the first td and let it float

```css
/* pseudo tr:before for CSS COUNTER for table tr */


tbody {
  counter-reset: trs
}

tbody td:first-child:before {
  counter-increment: trs;
  content: counter(trs)'. ';
  float:left

}


/* end css counter */

body {
  font-family: '-webkit-system-font', 'HelveticaNeue-Light';
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js"></script>

<table class="sortable" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Play</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=1990">1990</a><br>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2000">2000</a><br>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2010">2010</a><br>data1</td>
      <td>data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/list.php?cat=decade&id=2020">2020</a><br>data3</td>
      <td>data4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```